# Yield in javascript to allow setTimeout() function to run?

Tags: javascript

I need to wait for a buffer to fill before invoking a function - and thus have sent the function onto the backburner for a few hundred milliseconds via `setTimeout()` . But that invocation only happens *much* later - after the entire data processing is completed and so the current script has ended.

Can a `yield` - or something equivalent - be inserted into the main flow to allow the delayed function an opportunity to wake up closer to its originally scheduled timing?

Comment: What *backburner*? What do you mean with "to wake up closer to its originally scheduled timing"? Can you setup an [MCVE] so we can at least understand what you are doing? Sounds like you'd be better with a WebWorker here. What do you expect from blocking the filling function?

Comment: The problem with the `webworker` is that the logic in the `setTimeout` is supposed to access somewhat sizeable in-memory buffers.  I'd rather not transmit that data through queues to/from the webworker.  But if needbe then `webworkers` are the backup plan.

Comment: You can *transfer* buffers between contexts or even use SharedArrayBuffers if you wish (in recent browsers).

Comment: Interesting. But we need to support both ios-Safari and android browsers so apparently `SAB`'s are not an option

Comment: You can still transfer ArrayBuffers for no memory cost..`

Comment: I'm looking at that - looks promising. I'm guessing there were _no_ equivalent of yielding a thread in javascript. you can make this an answer if you like

Comment: There is, you can use a generator function which will allow you to yield any value, you could even use an async function and await for some delayed Promise, but your question is unclear as to why you'd need any of these, so I can't even post an answer, because you're not asking the correct question.